# Overwriting when merging dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

Say we have 2 dictionaries the first one is extracted using openpyxl from a file named excel2013.xlsx and the second one from excel2014.xlsx:

```
d1={'nume': 'Barta', 'cifra afaceri': 200, 'cifra2': 24}
d2={'nume': 'Barta', 'cifra afaceri': 190, 'cifra3': 21}
```

These dictionaries are part of a list of dictionaries.

```
lista=[{'nume': 'Barta', 'cifra afaceri': 200, 'cifra2': 24},{'nume': 'Barta', 'cifra afaceri': 190, 'cifra3': 21}]
```

Firstly, what i want to do is go over this list and find duplicates based on one key, in this case, the key 'nume'. From these duplicates i need to obtain a new dictionary containing all the keys from both d1 and d2. My solution is this:

```
import os
import itertools
ultima_lista=[]
ultima=[]
for a, b in itertools.combinations(lista,2):
    if a['nume'] == b['nume']:
        z=dict(list(a.items())+ list(b.items()))
        ultima_lista.append(z)
print(*ultima_lista, sep='\n')
print('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
for a in lista:
    for b in ultima_lista:
        if a['nume'] == b['nume']:
            ultima.append(a)
print (*ultima, sep='\n')
print('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
for i in ultima_lista:
    lista.append(i)
for i in ultima:
    lista.remove(i)
print(*lista, sep='\n')
```

Now this solution is made for a larger list, we only have 2 dicts in example here. However, using this method i cannot control for the key 'cifra afaceri' which data is overwritten- which data remains, from dict1 or from dict2. In this example i would need the latest information, which is excel2014 to be on top, meaning that my desired output should be:

```
lista=[{'nume': 'Barta', 'cifra afaceri': 190, 'cifra2': 24,'cifra3': 21 }
```

I was thinking to make another dict in which the keys are the elements from 'lista' and the values are the years that i extract from the filenames.Ideas?|Thx

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! After you post a question, please take the time to look it over: you forgot to use proper syntax to format your code and your post consequently looked like a mess. Someone had to edit it for you, and it's much nicer if they don't have to because you followed the posting instructions =)

Comment: I don't think I understand. Is what you want just `d1.update(d2)`?

Comment: @Batman in this example it would work but imagine u have 10 dictionaries with the same 'nume' key. and maybe the one which is the latest does not have all the keys the others have.

Comment: @Mike in case of many dicts start from oldest to latest. For e.g d1, d2, d3, d4 (in order oldest to latest) then merge d1 with d2 then merge result of first merge (d1.update(d2)) with d3 and so on

Comment: @Mike Are you sure this will work? Because `d1['cifra afaceri']` gives 190 but `d2['cifra afaceri']` gives 200. So you can not have them both in a single dictionary.

Comment: @HarshalDhumal thing is when i used openpyxl to convert 50 sheets from 50 xlsx files into a list of dictionaries, one for each row in each sheet, i dont have them ordered like d1,d2, d3 etc. i just have the list of dicts.

Comment: @Elmex80s i only need one of them.

Comment: I haven't used openpyxl but If I understood it correctly you can open xlsx files in oldest to latest  order e.g open excel2013 first add rows to list of dict then open excel2014 and repeat. And since list is ordered collection you will have oldest element first in list of dict always you don't have to worry about list ordering provided that you opened files in oldest to latest order.

Comment: @HarshalDhumal ur right but i need a solution for an indefinite number of xlsx, say u have 100 in a folder, u appy some criteria and remain with 40. each of these has 300-500 rows. it s really inefficient to open them up multiple times. However, if i wont find any other solution i will take your advice and after applying the criteria i ll find a way to open them up in a specific order- this will change my entire code...

Comment: Note this question has not much to do with Excel so I wouldn't mention Excel in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe keep a list as the value in the dictionary and append values from each dictionary. That way, values that have the same key will be in a list. In addition to that, the last dictionary you loop through will be appended to the end of the list so you can use that as your "priority".

```
d1={'nume': 'Barta', 'cifra afaceri': 200, 'cifra2': 24}
d2={'nume': 'Barta', 'cifra afaceri': 190, 'cifra3': 21}
result=dict()

for key, value in d1.items():
    if key in result:
        result[key].append(value)
    else:
        result[key] = [value]

for key, value in d2.items():
    if key in result:
        result[key].append(value)
    else:
        result[key] = [value]

print(result)

>>> {'cifra afaceri': [200, 190], 'cifra2': [24], 'cifra3': [21], 'nume': ['Barta', 'Barta']}
```

**Edit**

If you don't need the previous values for duplicate keys, you can just use `update` as someone suggested in the comments to the questions. You just need to update with the highest priority last (e.g. last update should be the latest Excel sheet so their values take priority).

```
d1={'nume': 'Barta', 'cifra afaceri': 200, 'cifra2': 24}
d2={'nume': 'Barta', 'cifra afaceri': 190, 'cifra3': 21}
d3={'something': 'Barta', 'something else': 198, 'cifra3': 100}
result=dict()

# The order here is the priority, last update ends up with its value
# for the given key if duplicates
d1.update(d2)
d1.update(d3)

print(d1)

>>> {'cifra2': 24, 'cifra afaceri': 190, 'nume': 'Barta', 'something else': 198, 'something': 'Barta', 'cifra3': 100}
```

Comment: This is a good idea but i am merging a lot of .xlsx files into 1 using openpyxl so i need only 1 value for each key, and that 1 value needs to be the newest one- meaning the dict has to come from the newes xlsx file, so when i dump them into the final excel i have one value per cell.

Answer (score 0):

How about `groupby` the key `nume` first and then do the dict update later on:

```
from itertools import groupby

d = [{'nume': 'Barta', 'cifra afaceri': 200, 'cifra2': 24}, 
     {'nume': 'Barta', 'cifra afaceri': 190, 'cifra3': 21}, 
     {'nume': 'Daniel', 'cifra afaceri': 190, 'cifra3': 21}]

d_all = list()
for key, group in groupby(d, key=lambda x: x['nume']):
    d_update = dict()
    for d in group:
        d_update.update(d)
    d_all.append(d_update)
```

The output is as follows:

```
[{'cifra afaceri': 190, 'cifra2': 24, 'cifra3': 21, 'nume': 'Barta'},
 {'cifra afaceri': 190, 'cifra3': 21, 'nume': 'Daniel'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this

```
import itertools

temp = [x.items() for x in lista if x['nume'] == 'Barta']
flattened_temp = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(temp))

d1_and_d2_keys = set(d1.keys() + d2.keys())    

sub_answer = {k: v for k, v in flattened_temp if k in d1_and_d2_keys}

sub_answer['cifra afaceri'] = d2['cifra afaceri']
```